# Plotly - Make axis tick labels responsive

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

using react-plotly, I'm trying to make a few charts responsive. I'm running into issues that when someone is using a low resolution, the axis tick labels are overlapping with the legend, which is positioned below the charts as well.

Is there some clever way to counteract this? Trying to adjust the font size in css using selectors such as

```
.xtick > text
```

is quite a headache and doesn't result in a proper fix for me.

The legend itself is created like this:

```
  legend: {
    orientation: 'h',
    y: -0.05
  },
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an open issue that we're working on fixing, finally :) https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1199

Comment: Awesome, thanks for taking your time to reply here! Not sure if the question should be closed in similar cases. I'll click resolved for now (?).